# Spinner isnt visible when Android system dark mode enabled

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Heres the code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_control"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/frmL"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

and here's the <border_control>

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <stroke android:color="@color/design_default_color_on_primary" android:width="1dp"/>
  <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
  <solid android:color="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"/>
</shape>
```

[dark mode layout in it is the spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1QsO.jpg)

[in normal mode, you can see the spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSyT6.jpg)

EDIT - so what i did was made another folder named values-night and copied the color.xml file in it and changed the colors i was using to more darker, now i detects if the system night mode is enabled it picks colors from value-night forlder
if anyone was having same problem you can also do what i did this also gives your app a dark mode.

Comment: How are you forcing the dark mode off?

Comment: using this `android:forceDarkAllowed="false"`

Comment: It may be not the real solution to your problem, but try this to disable dark mode for your app

`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`

In your app onCreate

Comment: thanks for helping but i made a dark mode for my after a lot of searching lol

Answer (score 0):

Try to copy all from the values/themes.xml to the values-night/themes.xml. I'm sorry I can't make comments for now.

[image]

Comment: so what i did was make another forlder values-night
and in that make i copied the color.xml and just changed the color which were light to darker and it worked